# Seattle Sitecore User Group: Coveo for Sitecore Enterprise Edition on Cloud

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (PST):** Thursday, November 30, 2016, 5:30 - 7:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Friday, December 1, 2016, 1:30 - 3:30 AM

**Location:** POSSIBLE SEATTLE, 414 Olive Way, Suite 500, Seattle, WA 
Between 4th & 5th on Olive Way in downtown Seattle.

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-Seattle-User-Group-Meetup/events/235025634/

**Twitter:** [@SeattleSitecore](https://twitter.com/SeattleSitecore)

Please join us for the next Sitecore Seattle User Group meeting!

In addition to terrific networking with technical and marketing professionals, we'll be joined by Nicolas Bordeleau and his colleagues from Coveo.  They'll be presenting about the Coveo for Sitecore Enterprise Edition on Cloud, which includes access to a broad connector library, advanced search usage analytics tools and integration with the Sitecore Experience Database to create persona-driven experiences. Also, Nick will be covering CoveoReveal, a patent-pending, analytics-based machine learning service.

Refreshments will be provided.

Comment: Posted on Community Bulletin. Community Bulletin promotion begins on Nov 21 at 1:30

Comment: Will this be broadcasted?

Comment: As far as I know, it will not be broadcasted.  Please check @seattlesitecore twitter for updates.  Thanks!